# Yesod route interpolation in Julius via widgetFile

Tags: yesod, yesod-julius

I think `@{SomeRouteR}` should work in `.julius` files, as described in:

https://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates#shakespearean-templates_julius_javascript

Everything was working when I first had this in my Handler:

```
toWidget [julius|   
                        $("#examplespan").click(function(){                                                                               
                            $.ajax({                                                                                                      
                                url: @{ExampleR},                                                                                 
                                type: "POST",   
                                ...

                        |]
```

But now that I've changed my Handler to work like this:

```
$(widgetFile "example")
```

I added this code in `example.julius`:

```
                        $("#examplespan").click(function(){                                                                               
                            $.ajax({                                                                                                      
                                url: @{ExampleR},                                                                                 
                                type: "POST",   
                                ...
```

I now get the error:

```
[Error#yesod-core] expected EUrl but got Nothing for: DerefIdent (Ident "ExampleR")
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ./Text/Shakespeare.hs:441:27 in shakespeare-2.0.20-3iMfZ8A5DXH3Twhu6IoWNc:Text.Shakespeare @(yesod-core-1.6.9-7g4SwkDmJJ261rdNBKrLzX:Yesod.Core.Class.Yesod ./Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs:662:5)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might not be anything wrong here. I will copy in a troubleshooting note I have written previously for my company.

---

## DerefBranch Error from a Template File

> I made a change in a template (`{*.hamlet,*.cassius,*.lucius,*.julius}`) and I get an error like this:
>
> ```
> \"rawJS\")) (DerefBranch (DerefIdent (Ident \"tshow\")) (DerefIdent (Ident
> \"errors\")))\nCallStack (from HasCallStack):\n error
> ```

This is an issue with [I believe] template Haskell and the way that we're compiling. Maybe it's some GHC flags, maybe it's GHCi itself, I'm not sure.

You can resolve this by touching the file that references the template, *e.g.*, if your template file is `templates/foo.julius`, and you reference it with `$(widgetFile "foo")` in the `Handler.Foo` module, then touch (or save from your editor) the `src/Handler/Foo.hs` file and reload GHCi.

Comment: Hey Jezen! Thank you friend, I will try this out when I am at the computer next. I remember it coming and going in a spooky manner, so maybe this explains it!